# Modem Manager Program for Linux

Tags: linux, qt, ubuntu, modem

I am planning to create a Modem Manager program for a USB Modem (GSM). However I am uncertain on how to implement the features using QT/C++ on Ubuntu/Linux.

The graphical program window will show detils like network strength and carrier's name, as well as be able to access SMS and contacts on the SIM card.

It will feature a connect button to connect to the network and USSD option to check balance and data usage. These features are available to the users using this modem on Windows.

How can one implement them on Linux? Any tutorial or article to start with. I am ready to research and practise but don't know where to head?

Comment: I would start here: http://www.freedesktop.org/software/ModemManager/api/latest/. ModemManager provides [D-Bus](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/dbus/) interface. Qt and D-Bus: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/intro-to-dbus.html